# Sqoop unable to import --as-parquetfile

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm using Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.4.0.0-169 on hortonworks sandbox with HDP 2.4.

I'm getting below error when I execute sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test --username root --password test --table details --m 1 --target-dir /test_parq_sqoop --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --as-parquetfile --verbose
```

> org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/test_parq_sqoop. Check that JARs for hdfs datasets are on the class path.

Comment: Are you able to import other formats? I was under the impression that Parquet is mostly accepted in Cloudera distributions

Answer (score 0):

put the jar file into classpath lib.

check the hadoop classpath. Then check the required jar is there or not. most probably its not there because thats error said that so put it in to that directory and restart manager.

Comment: check the hadoop classpath. Then check the required jar is there or not. most probably its not there because thats error said that so put it in to that directory and restart manager.

Comment: I figured out the solution...i was able to import in Avro and other format but the problem is just with parquet...kitesdk used for converting to parquet only takes full URI as target directory....so when i gave full URI in --target-dir, e.g: --target-dir /usr/root/sqoop instead of --target-dir /sqoop.